# Feature Hashing

Tags: hash, machine-learning, nlp

I know that [feature hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) is a technique to vectorize features; it's very common for Machine Learning purposes. 
I am still confused in how it works when you want to track the term-frequency when there are collisions. Let's follow the same example given by Luis Argerich in [this](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-explain-feature-hashing-in-an-easily-understandable-way) link.

Let's say your text is: "the quick brown fox" and let's suppose you have the next hash function:

```
h(the) mod 5 = 0
h(quick) mod 5 = 1
h(brown) mod 5 = 1
h(fox) mod 5 = 3
```

Your final vector will be like: (1,2,0,1,0)

Now let's suppose your text is:  "the quick brown fox quick quick quick quick"
Now the final vector will be like:  (1,6,0,1,0)

My question is, how do I realize that brown appears just once and quick appears 5 times? how do I track that?

Comment: That is confusing to me.  If you are trying to deal with frequency TF-IDF with feature hashing may be the way to go.   The is ML site on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, how do I realize that brown appears just once and quick appears 5 times? how do I track that?

You don't. That's the whole trick with hashing. It **unifies** some thing, **losses** information so you can get other benefits. If you want to keep track of everything you should just use **bag of words**, not hashing.

The other option is more complex approach to hashing, like the one used in LSH techniques, which use family of hash functions to reconstruct final similarity, through showing that given big enough sample of hash functions - it converges to true similarity.